# Fragment not shown when clicking on Drawer

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation-drawer

I am creating a simple drawer layout in an android app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinator_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
       <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
       <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways|scroll" />
         </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
     </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
     <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
         android:id="@+id/nav_view"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="left"
         app:menu="@menu/main_mmm"/>

 </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The menu items are as follows:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_login"
            android:title="Login"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_game"
            android:title="Game"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_score"
            android:title="Score"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
            android:title="Settings"
            android:checked="true"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_about"
            android:title="About"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_help"
            android:title="Help"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_videos"
            android:title="Video"/>
    </group>
 </menu>
```

In the main activity's onCreate I do as follows:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
    var drawerLayout = findViewById<DrawerLayout>(R.id.drawer_layout)
    mDrawerToggle = object : ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout,    R.string.drawer_open_content_description, R.string.drawer_closed_content_description) {
        override fun onDrawerClosed(view: View) {
            lateinit var newFragment:Fragment

            when(mSelectedItem) {
                R.id.nav_settings -> {
                    newFragment = SettingsFragment()
                    supportActionBar?.setTitle("Preferences")
                }
            }

            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.main_content, newFragment)
                .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
                .commit();

            mSelectedItem = 0
        }
    }

    var navigationView = findViewById<NavigationView>(R.id.nav_view)
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        mSelectedItem = it.itemId
        it.setChecked(true)
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(navigationView)
        true
    }

}
```

When the navigationview listener is called it should save in mSelectedItem with one of the ids in the menu. But that does not happen. Instead an apparent random value is saved inside the mSelected item value. Can anyone please help ?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently not showing the correct itemId was because of a debugging issue of android studio that does not debug correctly in lambda functions.

The solution was to add the following function call in the onCreate method:

```
drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle)
```

I found this by debuggin in the method onDrawerClosed and observing that the method was not being called.

Final version of the onCreate method is:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
    var drawerLayout = findViewById<DrawerLayout>(R.id.drawer_layout)
    mDrawerToggle = object : ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open_content_description, R.string.drawer_closed_content_description) {
        override fun onDrawerClosed(view: View) {
            lateinit var newFragment:Fragment

            when(mSelectedItem) {
                R.id.nav_settings -> {
                    newFragment = SettingsFragment()
                    supportActionBar?.setTitle("Preferences")
                }
            }

            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.main_content, newFragment)
                .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
                .commit();

            mSelectedItem = 0
        }
    }
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle)

    var navigationView = findViewById<NavigationView>(R.id.nav_view)
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener { menuItem ->
        mSelectedItem = menuItem.itemId
        menuItem.setChecked(true)
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(navigationView)
        true
    }

}
```